# Saving Single Post request to multiple database models

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have multiple users and I designed two models for two users and the rest is super user.
And I have the model User that holds common data for all users.
I want to save the patient post request to two different models: User and Patient; I tried these codes but, didn't work.

This is my Signup view

```
class PatientSignupView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=PatientSignupSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_serializer=self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user=user_serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user":UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "patient":PatientSerializer(patient, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token":Token.objects.get(user=user).key,
            "message":"account created successfully",
       })
```

And here is my Signup Serializer class

```
class PatientSignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password_confirm = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type":"password"}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'is_doctor', 'is_patient', 'password', 
'password_confirm']

        extra_fields = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user=User(
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
            email=self.validated_data['email']
        )
        password=self.validated_data['password']
        password_confirm=self.validated_data['password_confirm']
        if password !=password_confirm:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"error":"password do not match"})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_patient=True
        user.is_doctor=False
        user.save()
        PatientSerializer.serialized_data(user)
        return user
```

Here is the PatientSerializer and UserSerializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Patient, User

    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username','email','is_doctor','is_patient']

    class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'gender']

        def serialized_data(self, user, **kwargs):
            patient = Patient.objects.create(
                user = user,
                first_name=self.validated_data['first_name'],
                middle_name = self.validated_data['middle_name'],
                last_name = self.validated_data['last_name'],
                address = self.validated_data['address'],
                phone_number = self.validated_data['phone_number'],
                birth_date = self.validated_data['birthh_date'],
                gender = self.validated_data['gender']
            )
            return patient
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved like this
The signup view is:

```py
class PatientSignupView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=PatientSignupSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_serializer=self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user=user_serializer.save()

    return Response({
            "user":UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token":Token.objects.get(user=user).key,
            "message":"account created successfully",
    })
```

The serializer class will looks like:

```py
class PatientSignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password_confirm = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type":"password"}, write_only=True)
    first_name  = serializers.CharField()
    middle_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name   = serializers.CharField()
    address     = serializers.CharField()
    phone_number= serializers.CharField()
    birth_date  = serializers.DateTimeField()
    gender      = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = {'password': {'write_only': True},}

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user=User(
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
            email=self.validated_data['email']
        )
        password=self.validated_data['password']
        password_confirm=self.validated_data['password_confirm']
        if password !=password_confirm:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"error":"password do not match"})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_patient=True
        user.is_doctor=False
        user.save()
        Patient.objects.create(user=user,
                    first_name=self.validated_data['first_name'],
                    middle_name=self.validated_data['middle_name'],
                    last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'],
                    address=self.validated_data['address'],
                    phone_number=self.validated_data['phone_number'],
                    birth_date=self.validated_data['birth_date'],
                    gender=self.validated_data['gender'])
        return user
```